# Azure ARM app service storage mount no longer works

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a docker container to an azure appservice with a storage mount  declared, this was previously working but doesn't seem to anymore ? according to the documentation it should be doable using azureStorageAccounts on siteConfig .. but no matter what i try this now seems broken, have also raised on the ms community site ..

ARM template sample is something like this (when using slots, have also tried using it without slots)

```
    "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appServiceSlotName')]",
      "type": "slots",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('App').name)]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "siteConfig": {
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "ftpsState": "Disabled",
          "http20Enabled": true,
          "linuxFxVersion": "[concat('DOCKER|', variables('App').ContainerImage)]",
          "azureStorageAccounts": {
            "appdata": {
              "type": "AzureFiles",
              "accountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
              "shareName": "api",
              "accessKey": "[parameters('storageAccountKey')]",
              "mountPath": "/home/appdata"
            }
          },
          "appSettings": "[variables('App').Settings]"
        },
        "httpsOnly": true,
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "reserved": true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Does anyone know if something changed ? (seemed to break around the same time they changed how config looks in the portal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a regression on Azures fault and will be fixed in an upcming patch.